# Google Navigation intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm trying to launch Google Navigation directly from my application such that it would navigate me from a start address to a destination address. So I have the Latitude and Longitude coordinates for both start and destination address and would like to get the navigation for those. But I can't figure out how to provide a start address. Navigation only uses my GPS to obtain my current info. This is how I launch the intent:

```
        String mLat = "46.849861";
        String mLong ="-120.541992";
        String dLat = "38.062419";
        String dLong = "-99.173584";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +dLat+","+dLong));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by current address? Do you want to get user's lat and long values?

Comment: Not exactly. I might have phrased this wrong. I have 2 Addresses. One is the start address and the other is destination address. The start address doesn't necessarily have to be the users current address. But when I use the intent above I always get the users current location as the start address. I will modify this in my question

Comment: Navigation is based on current location. So providing a starting address does not make sense. How do you use the navigation from New York to New Jersey when you are in San Francisco?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I believe this uses Google Maps and not Google Navigation? I would like to use only Google Navigation and not Google Maps

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to do it. There might be undocumented ways to technically doing it, but I would prefer not to use them as they can be changed any time. The offically supported ways of invoking Google apps are here - http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html