# Navigation Intent on Android is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation

I would like to call a navigation Intent using given source and destination point, by the way I am trying these codes

```
Intent navIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="sourcelat&long"&daddr="destinationlat&long"&mode="driving"));
navIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");startActivity(navIntent);
```

As per the method above I am getting the navigation fine but by default destination address is taken as current location eventhough we are passing the destination address. so my need is that device should not take destination address as current device location instead it should take from Intent as we are passing . Please suggest me how to solve this.

Regards
Priya

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way i think.
But it use Google Maps and not Google Navigation.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Source: [Google Navigation intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280309/google-navigation-intent)

Comment: Thats okay, for example I have posted like this. but my question is why it is taking current location as default even if we specify the destination lat and longitude

Comment: Thanks yaar, But i need navigation with given source and destination

Comment: There is no standard way to do it with Google Navigation. There maybe unofficial ways it can be done. But i would not use them because they can be changed everytime. The official supported ways are here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html