# Show Location in Google Maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to start Google Maps and show the Location that are saved in `String`'s

```
String street = projectItems.get(position).get(project_company_street);
String zip = projectItems.get(position).get(project_company_zip);
String city = projectItems.get(position).get(project_company_city);
```

I made something that doesn't meets my conditions.

```
Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + street + "," + zip + "+" + city);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, IntentUri);
```

So if User presses the Button, Google Maps starts in Navigation Mode.

How can I just show the Location of it?

Hope my problem is clear.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your Uri to this:

```
Uri IntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + street + "," + zip + "+" + city);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution!

Comment: Can you mark it as a answer, if it worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by providing latitude and longitude of both current and destination locations like below

```
String sAddr = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%s,%s&daddr=%s,%s";
String sAddr2 = String.format(sAddr, cur_lat, cur_long, dest_lat, dest_long);
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(sAddr2);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivityForResult(mapIntent, GoTo_MAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example :

```
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia&mode=b");
 Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
 mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
 startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Ref : [Google Navigation intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280309/google-navigation-intent)